# Regex for parsing links from html page doesn't work where href tags doesn't have quotes around

Tags: regex

I have noticed that some html pages doesn't put " or ' around href tags, so that means that my regex string below won't get the link..

```
<a.*?href=["",'](.*?)["",'].*?>([\s\S]*?)</a>
```

What would I have to change about this, to make it work for all three cases? I've tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
<a.*?href=["",',](.*?)["",',].*?>([\s\S]*?)</a>
```

Comment: Which _three cases_?

Comment: If the href tag has " or ' or nothing around it, right now it only gets it if it has " or ' around it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the " or ' optional (using ? after the close group ]), and to make it more reliable, replace some of the wild-card grabs with more explicit stopping points.

```
<a.*?href=["']?([^'">\ ]*)["']?[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test this shortly.